# One-sided Bound on Sum of Fourth Moments

Tags: probability, inequality, normal-distribution, concentration-of-measure

I'm interested in methods for proving one-sided bounds of the form
$$
\mathbb{P}[\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X^4_i \geq 3+t]\leq Ce^{-nt}
$$
where $X_i$ are standard normal random variables.  I've run a few basic random experiments, it seems that this should be possible for t relatively large (but independent of $n$).  Note that I don't care about concentration, just a loose upper bound.

Is this possible?

Comment: Did you mean $\geq 3+t$? As it is written, the inequality doesn't make sense: consider very large $t$ for example. The LHS goes to $1$ whereas the RHS goes down to $0$.

Comment: Also as $n \to \infty$, since $\mathbb E[X_i^4] = 3$, the left side goes to $1$ for any fixed $t > 0$. $\mathbb P[n^{-1} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^4 \ge 3 + t]$ does decay exponentially by Cramér's theorem from Large Deviations theory.

Comment: Hi @RobertIsrael, would you mind elaborating on the exponential decay?  I'm not familiar with Cramer's Theorem, and the few things I found online don't state the theorem in a clear enough form (to me at least).

Comment: @RobertIsrael The random variables $X^4$ have no finite exponential moments hence Cramér needs at least some tweaking before being an option.

Comment: The result is false as $t\to\infty$ even for $n=1$.

Comment: @Did : You're right,  I forgot about that.

Comment: Indeed, $P(X_1^4 > (3+t) n)$ itself decays slower than exponentially, more like $\exp(-(3+t)^2 \sqrt{n}/2)$ I think.